# Special names in Latex

Tags: latex

In my english thesis latex file, how to mention the following non English words: François, École Fédérale?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Close voters should consider http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7135/where-should-a-question-about-latex-usage-go

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The traditional way is to use the accent-adding macros:

```
Fran\c{c}ois
\'Ecole F\'ed\'erale
```

(You can also write `Fran\c{}cois` or `Fran\c cois`; the `\c` macro uses no parameter; the braces or space are just a trick to allow LaTeX to see the proper macro name.)

Otherwise, try this:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and type the accents directly, with UTF-8 encoding.

There are a host of more-or-less subtle issues with fonts and hyphenation.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't go the UTF8 inputenc route, and yet find yourself writing a lot of these names, I'd suggest defining macros for them.  At the simplest, you can say

```
\newcommand\Francois{Fran\c cois}
```

but then you need to be sure to use it as such: `\Francois{}` so that any spaces afterwards don't get gobbled.

On the other hand, the following technique works pretty well too (though I can't take credit for inventing it - I saw it originally in a short talk at BachoTeX 2009 by Philip Taylor):

```
\makeatletter
\let\latex@less<
\catcode`<13
\def<{\ifmmode\latex@less\else\expandafter\find@name\fi}
\def\find@name#1>{\@nameuse{name.#1}}
\def\DefineName#1#2{\@namedef{name.#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

Now you can define special names using, e.g.

```
\DefineName{Francois}{Fran\c cois}
\DefineName{Ecole Federale}{\'Ecole F\'ed\'erale}
```

and later on you can use them in text with

```
I ran into <Francois> at the <Ecole Federale> the other day.
```

You can make your tags (the plain ASCII versions) be whatever you want - they don't have to actually be related to the properly accented names.

---

EDIT: in response to the issue that misspelled names don't produce errors, you can change the definition of `\find@name` to

```
\def\find@name#1>{\ifcsname name.#1\endcsname
  \@nameuse{name.#1}%
\else
  \@latex@warning{Undefined name #1}%
\fi}
```

Note that `\@latex@warning{...}` can be changed to `\@latex@error{...}\@eha` and it will complain more forcefully.  Or if you want to pretend to be (or actually be) a package you can use `\Package(Warning|Error){<package name>}` in place of `\@latex@(warning|error)` and it won't pretend to be a built-in LaTeX error anymore.

Comment: +1; interesting trick!  A small remark, though: mistyped “keywords” (e.g. <francois>) expand to a blank without producing any warning/error.